How to delete filtered dates in Excel using VBA?
I have an Excel table that contains different dates, such as a "move in date" column. I'm trying to filter the column so it shows only the entries that are set after a certain date, e.g., 1 May 2021, and then remove these rows so I'm left with only the dates pre 1 May 2021.
So far I have this but when I run it, I get the 'no cells were found' error despite having several entries in my table post 1 May 2021.
Any help would be really appreciated :)
Sub FilterMoveOut()

Dim lo As ListObject
Dim iCol As Long

Set lo = Sheet1.ListObjects(1)
iCol = lo.ListColumns("Move in date").Index

lo.AutoFilter.ShowAllData

With lo.Range

.AutoFilter Field:=iCol, Criteria1:=">=2021-05-01"

lo.DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete

lo.AutoFilter.ShowAllData

End With
End Sub


Real Dates (not dates as string) are stored as number in excel. Comparing are based on this. Therefore use either DateSerial or DateValue functions. More info you can get if type in the Search textbox [vba] date autofilter

Filter Excel Table by Date

With this setup, the rows to be deleted will only be selected.
This will delete rows only after you set IS_IN_TEST_MODE to False.

Sub FilterMoveOut()

    Const DATE_STRING As String = "2021-05-01"
    Const DISPLAY_MESSAGE As Boolean = True
    Const IS_IN_TEST_MODE As Boolean = True
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheet1
    Dim lo As ListObject: Set lo = ws.ListObjects(1)
    Dim lc As ListColumn: Set lc = lo.ListColumns("Move in date")
    
    Dim CriteriaColumn As Long: CriteriaColumn = lc.Index
    
    Dim AutoFilterState As Boolean: AutoFilterState = lo.ShowAutoFilter
    
    If AutoFilterState Then
        If lo.AutoFilter.FilterMode Then lo.AutoFilter.ShowAllData ' clear
    End If
    
    lo.Range.AutoFilter Field:=CriteriaColumn, Criteria1:=">=" & DATE_STRING
    
    Dim frg As Range, AreFilteredRowsFound As Boolean
    
    On Error Resume Next
        Set frg = lo.DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        AreFilteredRowsFound = (Err.Number = 0)
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If AutoFilterState Then
        lo.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
    Else
        lo.ShowAutoFilter = AutoFilterState
    End If
    
    Dim DeletedRowsCount As Long
    
    If AreFilteredRowsFound Then
        DeletedRowsCount = frg.Rows.Count
        If IS_IN_TEST_MODE Then
            ws.Activate
            frg.Select
        Else
            frg.Delete Shift:=xlShiftUp
        End If
    End If
    
    If DISPLAY_MESSAGE Then
        If AreFilteredRowsFound Then
            MsgBox DeletedRowsCount & " filtered row" _
                & IIf(DeletedRowsCount = 1, "", "s") & " deleted.", _
                vbInformation
        Else
            MsgBox "No filtered rows found!", vbExclamation
        End If
    End If

End Sub


Can you elaborate what is the difference to the code of OP. On the first glance the filter looks the same to me, and OP asks why it finds no rows.

VBA speaks American English, so try a date in US format:
.AutoFilter Field:=iCol, Criteria1:=">=05/01/2021"


We get some strange behaviours using SpecialCells.  They can be avoided by the trick I use in my code of shifting the ListObject'sragne down and deleting it.  Excel will not delete filtered out rows long as there is one visible row to delete.
Sub FilterMoveOut2()
    With Sheet1.ListObjects(1)
        .AutoFilter.ShowAllData
        .Range.AutoFilter Field:=.ListColumns("Move in date").Index, Criteria1:=">=2021-05-01"
        
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        .Range.Offset(1).Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
            
        .AutoFilter.ShowAllData
    End With
End Sub

